# convert from struct tm to std::time_t and convert back date will be changed

Tags: c++, time

i try to convert from struct tm, to std::time_t
with the following sample code :

```
void test_time_t() {
    tm time;
    time.tm_year = 2004-1900;
    time.tm_mon = 11;
    time.tm_mday = 5;
    time.tm_hour = 12;
    time.tm_min = 2;
    char buff[25];
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y %b %d %H:%M",&time);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    auto t = std::mktime(&time);
    struct tm *tmp = localtime(&t);
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y %b %d %H:%M",tmp);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
}
```

this will output :

```
2004 Dec 05 12:02
2005 Jun 16 22:41
```

the date is changed, can anybody tell me what i do wrong here?
i think timezone will not cause such different in date

Comment: Can't reproduce [online](https://godbolt.org/z/f4vYn1f9W), my code shows that possibly caused by timezone.

Comment: Those `struct`s shouldn't be there, and, rename the declaration `tm tm;` to something else.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin from you online code , i get the following result :                       2004 Dec 05 12:02
1969 Dec 31 23:59

Comment: Hell of a timezone to add on six months. This would be for what, Mars?

Comment: @Casey i tried remove struct  and rename tm to time , same result on my machine

Comment: `12:02 1969 Dec 31 23:59` is one second before the unix epoch. Often this is [the result of `mktime` reporting an error](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktime.html). If you print `t`, it should be -1  Follow the advice on the manpage and check `errno` (or use `perror` to get a plaintext explanation) to see if it helps youdiagnose the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your `time`:

```
tm time{}; // zero-initialized
```

---

> "*I just forget that `tm` is a `C` struct.*"

That's common. You can however inherit `std::tm` and use your own type in the code instead.

```
struct tm_ext : std::tm {
    tm_ext() : std::tm{} {}; // zero initialize on default construction
};
```

You can now use `tm_ext` without risking to miss the initialization:

```
tm_ext time; // now fine
```

While you're at it, you may even add some other convenience functions to it.

```
struct tm_ext : std::tm {

    tm_ext() : std::tm{} {}; // zero initialize on default construction

    explicit tm_ext(int year, int mon = 1, int mday = 1, int hour = 0,
           int min = 0, int sec = 0, int isdst = 0) :
        tm_ext() // delegate to default constructor
    {
        tm_year = year - 1900;
        tm_mon = mon - 1;
        tm_mday = mday;
        tm_hour = hour;
        tm_min = min;
        tm_sec = sec;
        // A negative value of tm_isdst causes mktime to attempt to determine if
        // Daylight Saving Time was in effect.
        tm_isdst = isdst;

        errno = 0;
        if(std::mktime(this) == -1 && errno != 0) {
            throw std::runtime_error("mktime failed");
        }
    }

    tm_ext(const std::tm& t) : std::tm(t) {} // conversion ctor

    operator std::time_t () const { // implicit conversion to time_t
        tm_ext copy(*this);
        errno = 0;
        return std::mktime(&copy);
    }

    // implicit conversion to a pointer - perhaps an exaggeration
    operator const tm_ext* () const { return this; }

    bool set_localtime(const std::time_t& t) {
        std::tm* tmp = std::localtime(&t);
        if(not tmp) return false;
        *this = *tmp;
        return true;
    }

    bool set_utc(const std::time_t& t) {
        std::tm* tmp = std::gmtime(&t);
        if(not tmp) return false;
        *this = *tmp;
        return true;
    }
};
```

And using it:

```
void test_time_t() {
    tm_ext time(2004, 12, 5, 12, 2); // use real world values
    
    char buff[25];
    // implicit conversion to a   const tm_ext*  below:
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y %b %d %H:%M", time);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    
    std::time_t t = time; // implicit conversion from tm_ext to time_t

    tm_ext tmp;
    if(tmp.set_localtime(t)) std::cout << "successfully set localtime\n";

    // implicit conversion to a   const tm_ext*  below:
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y %b %d %H:%M", tmp);

    printf("%s\n",buff);
}
```

Before going overboard with this, one may want to take a look at Howard Hinnant's [`date.h`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) though.

Comment: I just forget that `tm` is a C struct.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Easily done. I added some ideas of how to deal with that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's so cool. Just mentions that boost [DateTime](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html) is a related library for someone come here may like to use.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Yes and Howard Hinnant's `date.h` - Adding a link to that should be mandatory when fiddling about with this - but I forgot :-)

Comment: Note: If your compiler is up to date and supports the 2020 C++ Standard revision, date.h is pretty much built in to the `<chrono>` library.